# Django Whitenoise cache busting control

Tags: django, caching

I've run `manage.py collectstatic` and Whitenoise has post-processed all of the static files. I'm not quite sure what should i do now if i want to change/update some of the files, for example, my .css stylesheet? Should i run `manage.py collectstatic` every time files have been changed? I'm asking this because my development server takes about 45 minutes to finish that task, and i'm not sure if that's normal because i have only 550 static files, 250Mb total.

Secondly, as Whitenoise doesn't support serving media files i use Amazon CloudFront for that. How can i control cache busting with those media files that users have uploaded? This is very important for me.

Comment: You "only" have 250Mb of static files?!

Comment: Yes, is that too much? I have mostly .PDF files (some brochures) in my static folder, should i move them to media folder or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to run `collectstatic` every time your files change.

It's very unusual to have 250MB of static files. Also, because Django's cache busting creates a copy of each file with a unique name you'll end up with two copies of each file so that's 500MB already. On top of this WhiteNoise will be creating gzip-compressed versions of each file so you could be heading towards 1GB of files.

One quick way of speeding up this process would be to tell WhiteNoise not to compress your PDF files, which you can do by adding `.pdf` to the [WHITENOISE_SKIP_COMPRESS_EXTENSIONS](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#WHITENOISE_SKIP_COMPRESS_EXTENSIONS) setting.

It sounds like your brochures would be better stored as user media though, rather than static assets.

To control caching you should make your code generate a unique name for each file when it's uploaded (adding a random string as a prefix to the filename should do the trick). You can then set caching headers on these files for as long as you like.

Comment: Thank you, i've done as you suggested and moved my PDF files to my media storage (on S3, without Expires header), i have now 15MB of static files and it's all ok now. But i'm still unable to manage cache control. Let's take for example my app.css file in consideration. I have changed my file and run `collectstatic -c` but in web browser i still get old app.css file (with ctrl+f5 - ignoring cache content). If i change it's name in my html to app.1.css file i get 404 error, django is unable to find it. I still don't know what am i supposed to do after all this in order to make it to work?

Comment: Sorry, i have forgot to mention that i'm struggling with this in development mode if that matters, Debug is set to True, if i set it to False i get 500 server error.